# How to vectorize a mask matrix initialization?

Tags: python, numpy

I need the following mask matrix to multiply another one and in the context of computing a ML cost function. I basically have a vector Y or label responses and need to set the mask to 1 where `Y[i] == j` and zero everywhere else so I do:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10 # samples
k = 7  # labels
Y = np.array([6, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 6]).reshape(n, 1)
mask = np.zeros([n, k])
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(k):
        mask[i, j] = 1 if Y[i] == j else 0
print(mask)
```

Gives:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

How can this be done in a single liner vectorized format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try advanced indexing:

```
mask[np.arange(n), Y.flatten()] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With numpy, the `==` operator broadcasts across axes, so comparing your (n, 1) array with another (1, k) array will result in the full (n, k) array of comparisons:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10 # samples
k = 7  # labels
Y = np.array([6, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 6]).reshape(n, 1)
X = np.arange(k).reshape(1, k)
mask = (Y == X).astype(int)
print(mask)
```

(but for this case, @mathfux's answer is faster since you know each row only has a single `1` in it)